# JAVA: Space delimiting all non-numerical characters in a String

Tags: java, string, csv

I am having some trouble with modifying Strings to be space delimited under the special case of **adding spaces to all non-numerical characters**.

My code must take a string representing a math equation, and split it up into it's individual parts. It does so using space delimits between values This part works great if the string is already delimited.
The problem is that I do not always get a space delimited input. To deal with this, I want to first insert these spaces so that the array is created properly.

What my code must do is take any character that is NOT a number, and add a space before and after it.

Something like this:
3*24+321 becomes 3 * 24 + 321
or
((3.0)*(2.5)) becomes ( ( 3.0 ) * ( 2.5 ) )

Obviously I need to avoid inserting space in the numbers, or 2.5 becomes 2 . 5, and then gets entered into the array as 3 elements. which it is not.

**So far, I have tried using**

String InputLineDelmit = InputLine.replaceAll("\B", " ");

which successfully changes a string of all letters "abcd" to "a b c d"
But it makes mistakes when it runs into numbers. Using this method, I have gotten that:

(((1)*(2))) becomes ( ( (1) * (2) ) ) ---- * The numbers must be separate from parens

12.7+3.1 becomes 1 2.7+3.1 ----- * 12.7 is split

51/3 becomes 5 1/3 -----  * same issue

and 5*4-2 does not change at all.

**So, I know that \D can be used as a regular expression for all non-numbers in java.** However, my attempts to implement this (by replacing, or combining it with \B above) have led either to compiler errors or it REPLACING the char with a space, not adding one.

**EDIT:**

==== Answered! ====

It wont let me add my own answer because I'm new, but an edit to neo108's code below (which, itself, does not work) did the job. What i did was change it to check isDigit, not isLetter, and then do nothing in that case (or in the special case of a decimal, for doubles). Else, the character is changed to have spaces on either side.

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    String formula = "12+((13.0)*(2.5)-17*2)+(100/3)-7";

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++){

        char c = formula.charAt(i);
        char cdot = '.';

        if(Character.isDigit(c) || c == cdot) {
        builder.append(c);
        }
        else {
        builder.append(" "+c+" ");
        }
    }   

    System.out.println("OUTPUT:" + builder);


}
```

OUTPUT: 12 +  (  ( 13.0 )  *  ( 2.5 )  - 17 * 2 )  +  ( 100 / 3 )  - 7

However, any ideas on how to do this more succinctly, and also a decent explanation of StringBuilders, would be appreciated. Namely what is with this limit of 16 chars that I read about on javadocs, as the example above shows that you CAN have more output.

Comment: Actually, `\PN` is a non-numeric character in a regex; `\D` is the same as `[^0-9]` normally, or else the same as `\P{Nd}` under the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` compilation flag from Java 7.  BTW, your `"\B"` is missing a backslash because Java lacks 1st-class regexes.  Did you mean `"\\B"` — that is, `\B` — for a nonboundary?  Note that Java boundaries are broken before Java 7.

Comment: yes, I did mean \\B, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
String formula = "Ab((3.0)*(2.5))";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++){
    char c = formula.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
        builder.append(" "+c+" ");
    } else {
        builder.append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong iteration: you are using `charAt` where you need to use `codePointAt` in general-purpose code.  And you will have to bump your `i` one extra at times.  UTF-16 is a variable-width encoding, and your code is buggily treating it as though it were UCS-2.

Comment: Happy to see the answer helped & sad to see you can't upvote!

Comment: Yes. If we consider your qualifying statement of "Something LIKE THIS", then yes, you did answer my question correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I knew this would not be the final working answer. Glad you have it going.

Comment: It's been like a year, but I finally have 15 rep. So I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Define the operations in your math equation  `+ - * / ()`  etc
2. Convert your equation string to `char[]`
3. Traverse through the `char[]` one char at a time and append the read char to a `StringBuilder` object.
4. If you encounter any character matching with the operations defined, then add a space before and after that character and then append this t o the `StringBuilder` object.
   Well this is one of the algorithm you can implement. There might be other ways of doing it as well.

Comment: No, you don’t step through strings a char unit at a time. You step through them a codePoint at a time!